# Reducir la cantidad de ciclos for por la mitad

Tags: java

mi problema es muy básico pero me rompí la cabeza intentando y ya no se me ocurre la solución.
El tema es el siguiente:
tengo una función que recibe como parámetro un numero y lo va concatenando n veces en un string (como por ejemplo si el numero es un 5 el string es "555555"), luego retorno el modulo entre ese string y 1405.

```
 String s = "";
    


    for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {

       s= s + n;}

    return new Integer(s.toString()).mod(1405);
```

con números pequeños es rápido y fácil, pero yo quiero obtener el resultado con 8789454846845184765 (numero muy largo al azar) como parámetro.
La cantidad de iteraciones del ciclo for van a ser muy eternas (o sin fin), mi primera idea es que sea la mitad de las vueltas por lo que ahora va mi pregunta:

¿Como reduzco a la mitad ( o menor) la cantidad de iteraciones del ciclo for?

Comment: Si simplemente quieres hacer menos iteraciones podrías hacer `s = s + n + n + n + n + n;` y en vez de `i++` usar `i+=5`. Con eso estarías haciendo un 80% menos de iteraciones. Problema? Tendrás que comprobar que no te pases, puesto que para `n = 7` hará 10 inserciones igual. Tendrás que meter una comprobación para que cuando `i + 5 < n` solo insertes la diferencia entre `i + 5` y `n`

Comment: Me gusto tu respuesta benito, funciona perfectamente pero para un numero con 12 cifras sigue teniendo problemas, habra alguna resolucion donde vayamos de a "mitades"?

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo una manera que evita los bucles directamente:

```
String s = "";
int n = 12;
String result = new String(new char[n]).replace("\0", Integer.toString(n));
```

Puede parecer un poco raro, pero te lo explico:

1. Cuando creas un tipo primitivo `char`, java le asigna por defecto el valor "\0", también conocido como NUL en ASCII. Así que creamos un nuevo `String` a partir del valor de un `array` de `char` de longitud `n`.
2. A continuación, aplicamos el método `replace()` de la clase `String` que pide dos parámetros, primero, el texto o char a buscar y segundo, el valor por el que lo sustituye.

Con esto tenemos un `String` de `n` veces el número `n`.

Cualquier duda, pregunta!

Comment: Excelente, desconocia esa funcion. pero si el numero es mas grande que un int deja de funcionar?

Comment: Efectivamente, en java no se pueden crear arrays de tamaño de un Long, así que esto solo funcionará con valores inferiores a ~2147483646, de todas maneras, si usas Long y un valor superior a ese, 2147483647 ^ 2147483647 supera el límite de Long también, con lo cual el código no funcionará de ninguna manera con números tan grandes y Long, y deberás usar clases especiales para tratar los números